# Code First: How to express many to many when one side can be 0 or many?

Tags: ef-code-first

A developer can be affected to 0 or more task. A task needs at least one developer to be executed. How do I express that in Code first?

```
public class Task
{
   public int ID
   //more properties here

   public virtual ICollection<Developer> Developers { get; set; }
}

public class Developer
{
   public int ID
   //more properties here

   public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a regular many-to-many relationship, and it should get mapped correctly by default. Specific business (validation) rules do not change its nature.

You can implement [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) if you want to enforce specific cardinalities when saving.